# Including link to professor's page in resume

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv

I am applying for PhD positions in computer science. I have been fortunate to get the opportunity to research under some really good professors (specifically, one who has a high h-index, another who is the academic director of a large scientific institution). While these professors are respected, they are not pioneers in the field and so not known to *everyone*.

Thus, while mentioning that I worked with these professors (specifically in my resume, but in general wherever it's required), I usually include a link to their profile. **My question is, is there a specific format or convention that people follow while providing more information about a professor?**

For instance, many professors have multiple profile pages across different institutions that they're associated with---which one should be used then? Sometimes, they have poorly maintained profile pages but have really good research work, which makes their Google scholar page much more impressive. Some even have Wikipedia articles about them.

If I want to highlight different aspects about a professor, can I link different pages against their names? In my case, that would mean linking the Google Scholar page for the professor with the high h-index while linking the profile page of the professor holding the important position.

Comment: Most people interested will know how to find them...

Comment: If they're well-known enough to have a Wikipedia page I think it's pretty likely that others working in the field will know who they are.

Answer (score 4):

I would assume that someone really interested is capable of using a search engine. Personally, I would find it strange if there are any links.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a useless exercise at best. If the professors are as good as you say a quick Google search will offer all necessary information. Moreover, applications are often filtered through various HR/IT systems that may render links unusable. Some reviewers (myself included) will print physical copies of applications which makes URLs unlikely to be checked.

Generally, if you worked with someone your CV should say

Worked with X on Y which resulted in Z, where if Z is a published work then that should be referenced.

As a final note: just because you worked with someone good does not necessarily say anything about you. If you worked with someone and it resulted in something good- that’s more meaningful.

Comment: As long as both parties did something useful compared to just hanging on coat tails...

Answer (score 1):

To add on to the answers here, (from my experience) if you are applying via the graduate admissions portal, most of them parse your written documents (including CV, Resume, SoP, Personal Statement etc.) via some kind of a parser. Essentially meaning, it will be converted to plain text. The problem with hyperlinking is that, those will not be clickable in plaintext.
I know for a fact that this is true for Harvard's SEAS application (it was very clearly mentioned in their portal).

In my opinion, if you can succinctly mention the work you have done with the professor in your statements, it should speak for itself. And moreover, the research community is small and there is a good chance that professors from one university will know professors from the other who are working in a similar field.